# Does gamma ray burst self-lense by its own gravitation?

Tags: general-relativity

If gamma ray burst contain energy equivalent to the mass of the sun, then it would be bent by its own gravity and refocus periodically, right? It could possibly go on forever without dispersion, enabling it to travel across the universe?